# Vertical Slider with content

Tags: jquery, jssor

I am trying to Slide content vertically .There is nothing about Looping slides vertically in the documentation page.Only Vertical slider with images are there.I tried So Many options but it seems like my code is not working.Please Help me guys.After Adding all the codes,the contents are not sliding totally.

HTML Code

```
    <div class="fl testimonial">
                        <div class="homepage-row-1st">
                            <div class="chart"></div>
                            <p>Messges</p>
                        </div>

                    <!-- Message Slider -->
                        <div id="slider1_vertical" style="position: relative; margin: 0 auto;top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 385px; height: 274px;">
                         <div u="slides" style="cursor: move; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 385px;height: 274px; overflow: hidden;">
                         <div>
                        <div class="homepage-row-2nd">
                            <div class="fl comma">
                                <div class="comma-img"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="fl Message-desc">
                                <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s
                                </p>
                                <div class="parent-name">Mr. xx xx (parent), <i>Ohio</i></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="cb"></div>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                        <div class="homepage-row-2nd">
                            <div class="fl comma">
                                <div class="comma-img"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="fl message-desc">
                                <p>
                                    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s
                                </p>
                                <div class="name">xxx xxx (customer), <i>Ontario</i></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="cb"></div>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                        <div class="homepage-row-2nd">
                            <div class="fl comma">
                                <div class="comma-img"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="fl message-desc">
                                <p>
                                    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s
                                </p>
                                <div class="name">xxx xxx(customer), <i>Alaska</i></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="cb"></div>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Jquery Code

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        var options_for_testimonial = {
            $AutoPlay:true,
            $AutoPlayInterval: 4000,
            $PauseOnHover: 1, 
            $ArrowKeyNavigation: false,
            $SlideDuration: 800,
            $MinDragOffsetToSlide: 20,
            $SlideSpacing: 0,
            $DisplayPieces: 1,
            $ParkingPosition: 0,
            $UISearchMode: 1,
            $PlayOrientation: 2,
            $DragOrientation: 2,
        };
        var jssor_slider2 = new $JssorSlider$("slider1_vertical", options_for_testimonial);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have just tested your code, it worked.

In addition, you can improve the syntax of your code,
please replace `$DragOrientation: 2,` with `$DragOrientation: 2`.